# Decoding failed --system halted

Tags: boot

I was trying to ls my .ssh folder and I got

```
failed to read "." Input/output error
```

So I tried to reboot the system (ubuntu 21.04) and there was a lot of errors related to the disk. So I had switched off the PC by pressing and holding the power button. Now when trying to boot it up I get

```
Decoding failed
--System haled
```

Tried to boot the same kernel but in recovery mode, I get the same error as above after Initializing ramdisk

Booting with an older kernel gets me into recovery mode, but I don't know what to do.
Is there is a way to repair my ubuntu?
Thank you.

I'm attaching a screen when booting with older kernel.
[image: boot screen]

Added screens from disks
[image]

[image]

I also run fsck on my /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2
[image]

And even more SMART data. Still looks disk is OK.
[image]

Comment: Does it boot normally if you select an older kernel? Show me `ls -al /boot`. Start `Disks`, click the 3-dot button, choose SMART Data & Test, get to the Data window, take screenshots (the data is scrollable, so it may take more than one screenshot). Edit them into your question. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema , Thanks for response. Not it doesn't boot normally in a sense that it stops in emergency mode and doesn't follows through till gdm. Since I have no graphical shell I can't run Disks. I've attached a screen shot into question.

Comment: Please see my initial answer. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I've run the fsck on dev/sda1 and sda2 but to no avail :( I've attached screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hard disk may be failing... or has already failed... but let's try and check your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: I've run the fsck and rebooted but still got Decoding failed :( I've attached sreens to original post.

Comment: @vitalio Thanks for the update. Unfortunately your SMART Data window screenshot is not complete. The data is actually scrollable (although no scroll bar appears) and will require a second screenshot to be able to show me all of the information. Boot to the GRUB menu, Additional Options, and try and select the -59 or -53 kernel to boot (not Recovery Mode) and see if they boot. Do you have good backups? Is the disk actually 6+ years old? Report back.

Comment: I've added screen with more SMART data, but still looks like disc is OK.  Booting into older kernels gets me into emergency mode even when booting in normal (not recovery mode) I'm able to boot yes but it stops at emergency mode. The very first photo of screen is what happens when booting older kernel. I get root promt in emergency mode.

Comment: @vitalio Without seeing the disk error messages that you're seeing at boot time, or the lack of ability to review /var/log/syslog, it's hard to say what's wrong. Try to boot to Ubuntu Live USB, and try to backup your important files from hard disk to an external hard disk or flash drive, then try and reinstall Ubuntu. It may fail.

Comment: I'll try that I think. Back up, then install into sda1 leaving sda2 untouched and mounted as /home since it is previously also was /home. Basically just overwrite sda1. Might just work.

Comment: @vitalio Status please...

Comment: Still in progress didn't get time to reinstall yet.

Comment: It's been 10 days since my recommendation to backup and reinstall Ubuntu. When do you think that you'll have time to do this?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like several critical operating system files on your disk have been damaged.  This is likely due to multiple single block errors on the disk, leading me to suspect your disk is failing.

If your disk is failing, anything you do to modify the disk will make things worse.  If you have no data on the disk that you care about (or you have copies of it elsewhere), then the next step would be to run fsck on the partition as described in another answer.

However, if you do care about data on the disk, before you do anything to write to the disk, you should check if it is failing and copy the data off of it carefully, most important files first, as it may fail while you are reading it.

You can boot in rescue mode, or boot from install media in "Try Ubuntu" mode.
You can safely check if it is failing with

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda | less
```

/dev/sda is the most likely name of your disk, but you can get a list of all disks with `lsblk -d`

In the smartctrl output, you want to look at two sections.
Near the top, there should be a line that looks like:

```
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

That may instead say it has failed, or it may say failure is eminent, or it may say a test has never been performed.  If the last, you could run a test, but if the drive is failing, this could destroy data, so do data recovery first.

Next, look near the end of the list and see if it lists errors.

If there are no errors in the log, it is still uncertain if the drive is failing, so it is up to you if you want to do data recovery first, or go ahead and try filesystem repairs, or use `smartctl -t short /dev/sda` to run a short test and then check the logs again (about 2-3 minutes later).

If a short test still passes, it is still not certain the drive is not failing, but it is at least much much less likely.

Comment: Looks like SMART says my disk is OK

Answer (score 0):

My issue was on one of the installed `RAM` which has been failed. So after removing it, the problem is fixed.